# how to pass string data from swift to objective c class using notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, viewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I want to pass table cell text label data from swift class to objective c class. In swift class I did the following,

```
class NewsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var newsTableView: UITableView!

var myVC:NewsDetailsViewController!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    print("selected index :",indexPath.row)

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    print("did select and the text is \(selectedCell?.textLabel?.text)")
    myVC.passedValue = selectedCell?.textLabel?.text
    print("text label value: ", myVC.passedValue)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "PostQuestion"), object: myVC.passedValue)
    self.present(myVC, animated: true , completion: nil)

}
```

Now I want to receive this string data with my another controller which is a objective c class. Kindly guide.

Comment: if possible then pass string data with `prepareForSegue` method otherwise you can use `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Am not using any segue and NSUserDefaults is restricted in my project. So I want in Notification Center.

Comment: You should use the `userInfo` dictionary to pass data, and use `self` (the sender) as parameter for `object`. Is `myVC.passedValue` the correct value or should you not use `myVC.passedValue`?

Comment: myVC.passedValue? is correct. Will update. Could you please post some code sample for the same?

Comment: @NiravKotecha: `NSUserDefaults` is not intended for inter-controller communication. Notifications are the right way.

Comment: NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "PostQuestion"), object: nil, userInfo: challengeVC.passedValue)...Getting error as Cannot convert value of type 'String!' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]?'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send your notification with

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "PostQuestion"), 
    object: self,
    userInfo: ["value": myValue] as Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>)
```

and process the notifications it with something like

```
func processNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notifcation.userInfo

    if let value = userInfo?["value"] as? String {
        ...
    }
}
```

or the same in Objective-C

```
- (void)processNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *value = [notifcation.userInfo objectForKey:@"value"]

    if(value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: how to receive it in my objective c class?

Comment: no need of having this processNotification method name while sending data?

Comment: No, of course not. You can use (almost) any name you like. Only the signature must remain the same.

Comment: NSString *value = notifcation.userInfo[@"value"];...Error in obj c class like Array subscript is not an integer.

Comment: You can use `objectForKey:` instead.

Comment: So kind of you :) Thanks a ton.